# is it possible to prompt user with an error message if they click on a button that is disabled, JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

is it possible to prompt user with an error message if they click on a button that is disabled. e.g.

```
   JButton button = new JButton();
   button.addActionListener(this);
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   if(buttonClicked.getSource()== button){
    button.setEnabled(false);
   }
   }
```

Right now, when the user clicks on the button, the button gets disabled now once the button is disabled and the user clicks the button again, I want a error message to pop up saying something like 'you cannot click me again'

Comment: It is possible to have a flag in the code for an enabled button that triggers the display of an "I'm disabled" message.

Comment: No. A disabled component doesn't accept input therefore it doesn't fire events.

Comment: but that won't work, if the button is already disabled and the user clicks on it.

Comment: if the button is disable, and the user clicks on the button nothing happens

Comment: Right.  But if the button is *enabled* it can easily display a message saying "I'm disabled".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mouse listeners works even if component is disabled but visable. You can try using something like

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {// MouseAdapter is empty implementation
                                            // of MouseListener
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if (!b.isEnabled())
            System.out.println("you cannot click me again");
    }
});
```

---

Here is little example of more complete code

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(300, 300);

final AtomicBoolean justEnabled = new AtomicBoolean(false);
final JButton button = new JButton("click");

button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if (!b.isEnabled())
            if (justEnabled.get())
                justEnabled.set(false);
            else
                System.out.println("you cannot click me again");
    }

});

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
        b.setEnabled(false);
        justEnabled.set(true);
    }
});

JButton enabler = new JButton("enable");
enabler.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }
});

frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.add(button);
frame.add(enabler);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I am getting an error on the button variable in 'button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()' what is this variable representing?

Comment: Well, it is hard to say. Could you say something more about error? Did you add import to `MouseAdapter` which would be `import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;`?

Comment: its underlined in red and when I hover my mouse over it, it says 'button cannot be resloved'

Comment: Where you put this code? Is it at same level as `button.addActionListener(this);`. [Here is how your code can look like.](http://pastebin.com/HPf72Ts6)